# Fetching the next 3 or adjacent rows based upon a condition in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database of more than 10,000 rows. eg:

```
id text 
1  abc
2  ghj
3  cde
4  hif
5  klm
6  bbc
7  jkl
8  mno
9  dbo
10 ijk
```

I need to fetch the next three rows where the text matches a condition.

For eg: if I am doing a  text like '%bc% query it should return me rows with ids 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 as row #1 and #6 is a match

Comment: Read up on window functions.

Comment: can you please describe your output data logic more precisely

Comment: If match is found in row 1 and row 3, in that case what's the expected output?

Comment: The statement is: Select * from table where text like '%bc%'. It will return the row with ids 1 and 6.    I need the next 3 consecutive rows after 1 and 6.

Comment: @GauravS, in that case, the output shall be the rows 1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6. I am not concerned about the duplicates right now.

Comment: There is no such thing as  "the next" row in a relational database unless you can define a column to order by. Do you mean "the next three rows based upon the ordering of the `id` column"?

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get the desired result. I am assuming you want to calculate next based on ID only and ID is always increment by 1, as you have mentioned in question.

If ID doesn't always increment by 1 , then first add a ROW Number and then replace id in t2 subquery and join condition with row number.

```
select t1.id, t1.id_text 
from test t1
join
(
select id from test where id_text like '%bc%'
UNION
select id+1 from test where id_text like '%bc%'
UNION
select id+2 from test where id_text like '%bc%'
UNION
select id+3 from test where id_text like '%bc%'
) t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ad23/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
with -- Test data
  t(i, x) as (values
    (1,'abc'),(2,'ghj'),(3,'cde'),(4,'hif'),(5,'klm'),(6,'bbc'),(7,'jkl'),(8,'mno'),(9,'dbo'),(10,'ijk'))
select r.*
from
  t as t0 cross join lateral (
    select *
    from t
    where t.i >= t0.i
    order by t.i
    limit 4) as r
where t0.x like '%bc%'
order by r.i;
```

[Lateral joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) allows to use previous table in the next subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT next.*
FROM test, test next
WHERE test.text LIKE '%bc%'
  AND (test.id + 1 = next.id OR test.id + 2 = next.id OR test.id + 3 = next.id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am able to fetch the next 3 rows with this. If possible, I also want to include the row with the matching text i.e the rows with text '%bc%'

Comment: You can add `test.id = next.id` in the second condition (ie: `AND (test.id = next.id OR test.id + 1 = next.id OR test.id + 2 = next.id OR test.id + 3 = next.id)`) or you can simplify this condition using `BETWEEN` (ie: `AND next.id - test.id BETWEEN 0 AND 3`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to assume that the `id`s have no gaps.  One method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(text) over (order by id) as prev_text,
             lag(text, 2) over (order by id) as prev_text2,
             lag(text, 3) over (order by id) as prev_text3
      from t
     ) t
where text like '%bc%' or
      prev_text like '%bc%' or
      prev_text2 like '%bc%' or
      prev_text3 like '%bc%';
```

You can also do this with one comparison, using other window functions:

```
select id, text
from (select t.*,
             sum( (text like '%bc%')::int ) over (order by id rows between 3 preceding and current row) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 0;
```

With an index on `id`, this might be the fastest approach to solving the problem.